# Clearing notification after a few seconds

Tags: android, notifications

When you have the Messages Activity open and the phone receives a new message a notification is shown on the status bar. After a short amount of time the notification is removed.

Is it possible to do the same for my activity without using a timer to clear the notification after a few seconds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to use the NotificationManager only to cancel a notification, but you can do it with a simpler Handler.  Put some code like this right after you fire your notification.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
long delayInMilliseconds = 5000;
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(YourNotificationId);
    }
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Out of interest Why use a Handler rather than a Timer?

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of the classes enough to have a real reason, it's just an instinctive thing since you need something that runs once.  The Timer can be used to run once, but it can also be used to run repeatedly.  I always think of the Handler as something that runs one time when you tell it to, and that was your use case so it made sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

Well there is NO need of a Handler/Service while the `Notification.Builder` has the method `.setTimeoutAfter(long milliseconds)`:

Hence just call:

```
builder.setTimeoutAfter(time_in_milliseconds);
```

For more Information see [setTimeoutAfter(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long)).

Comment: I don't know why this isn't the accepted answer

Comment: what if I want to do an action when the user didn't interact with the notification and it get timeout

Comment: You will probably need a countdown timer for that. And if the time of waiting is too long. Show as a foreground service notification probably @lolowa

Comment: Note: it's No-op on versions prior to O (api v26)