# Make notification disappear after 5 minutes

Tags: android

Is it possible to make a notification automatically disappear after a period of time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing notification after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994126/clearing-notification-after-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can just create a service that runs in the background that'll timeout after five minutes and delete your notification. Whether you "should" actually do that is up for debate. A notification should be there to notify the user... and the user should be able to dismiss it on their own.

[From d.android.com:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). I think is more appropriate and more easier to implement than an Android Service.

With `AlarmManager` you do not need worry about make something running until the time finish. Android do that for you, and **send a brodcast** when it happen. Your application must have a **Receiver to get the correct intent.**

Look theses examples:

- [Android: How to use AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)
- [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an option called `.setTimeoutAfter(long durationMs)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is very easy.
Where you get notification there add one handler if notification is not read by user then remove notification.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
sendNotification(message.getData().toString);
}
```

**add notification code**

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("TEST NOTIFICATION")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int id = 0;
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
        removeNotification(id);
    }
```

**cancel notification code.**

```
private void removeNotification(int id) {
Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delayInMilliseconds = 20000;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a classic Java Runnable for a simple small Thread.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
    long delayInMilliseconds = 5000;
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Also look here:

[Clearing notification after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994126/clearing-notification-after-a-few-seconds)