# Auto Remove Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, firebase-notifications

I have a question, I have read both [Make notification disappear after 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648699/make-notification-disappear-after-5-minutes) and [Clearing notification after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994126/clearing-notification-after-a-few-seconds) , but I still don't understand the part where they call removing of the notification. I have a incoming firebase notification coming to my phone and If the user does not click on it,I want the notification removed/disappear automatically after 20 seconds. May I know how to implement it?

P.S I did read on the services as well. I am new to Java language and picking it up as I try a little demo. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

My codes below are crashing my app everytime i receive a notification. Any help will be appreciated.

Edited: Its fully functional. For anyone's reference

```
        private void removeNotification()
{
    long delayInMilliseconds = 20000; 
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(0);
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is very easy.
Where you get notification there add one handler if notification is not read by user then remove notification.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
sendNotification(message.getData().toString);
}
```

**add notification code**

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("TEST NOTIFICATION")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int id = 0;
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
        removeNotification(id);
    }
```

**cancel notification code.**

```
private void removeNotification(int id) {
Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delayInMilliseconds = 20000;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Hi Hulk, thanks for your reply, but for the cancel notification code, in public void run, we have to declare notificationManager again isnt it? if not we will have a unable to resolve symbol error

Comment: my App also crashes once my notification is received. I closed the app before i received my notification

Comment: Hi Hulk, sorry I cant do the error stack trace, because I am testing on the physical app itself, please refer to the codes above.

Comment: Hi Hulk, i solved the issue already, instead of handler, i am using timer to countdown then removing of the notification. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

as per i have implemented create new class and extends FirebaseMessagingService

you can write following code to send notification:

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("TEST NOTIFICATION")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

for cancel notification create new method and write following code:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
    long delayInMilliseconds = 20000;
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: please also refer this : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `ttl` in admin sdk of Firebase-Messaging. See [ttl Parameter for Android Config from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.androidconfig#androidconfigttl)

> AndroidConfig.ttl:
> Time-to-live duration of the message in milliseconds.

```js
function createMessage(
    title: string,
  body: string,
    fcmTokens: string[],
): MulticastMessage {
    return {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
        },
        android: {
            ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8, // 8 hours in millis,
        },
        tokens: fcmTokens,
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34547075)