# how can remove push value from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove the push value generated from firebase.Can I able to do that and how?

[image]

When user follow someone, I write some code to generate push value to firebase for notification. The problem is I didn't written code for removing the value when user unfollow and follows the user again and again it shows lots of notification ..like pic down below

```
    HashMap<String ,String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
            notificationData.put("from",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
            notificationData.put("type","following");
            mNotification.child(mUser.getUser_id()).push().setValue(notificationData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    setFollowing();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Why not change your datastructure to use the uid instead of a push id?

Comment: it will remove all value which as user_id

Comment: check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971390/auto-remove-firebase-notifications?noredirect=1&lq=1