# canceling firebase notification

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

Did anyone know how to cancel the notification if the client didn't receive it?
Is it possible to cancel sent push notifications?
does time_to_live or ttl in firebase object can help me?
**Please note that: this notification sent from backend application using C#**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Remove Firebase Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971390/auto-remove-firebase-notifications)

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge did you understood my question? i mean after sent the notification from c#? the answer is to use the time to live in firebase